# Nested If wont trigger ElseIf statement

Tags: vba, if-statement, do-while

This code loops through a column of data. If the cell in the column Is a WIP it goes to a corresponding column and loops through that data. If not it takes the data and pastes it in the summary tab. Yet for some reason it only picks up if the cell is a WIP and ignores the rest.

Can someone see why the code does not trigger my second IF.

```
    Sub summary_2()

    Dim MainLoop As Double
    Dim Secondloop As Double
    Dim TopRow As Double
    Dim ThirdLoop As Double

    Dim ParentName As String
    Dim ParentSku As Double
    Dim WipSku As String

    MainLoop = 5
    TopRow = 5

    Worksheets("Final").Activate

    Do While MainLoop < ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        ParentSku = Range("A" & MainLoop)
        ParentName = Range("B" & MainLoop)

        Worksheets("Summary 2").Activate

        Range("A" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) + 2) = ParentSku
        Range("B" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) + 2) = ParentName
        Range("C" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row) + 2) = "Parent"
        Range("D" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row) + 2) = " - "

        Worksheets("Final").Activate

        Do While Secondloop < 20

            'This If gets Triggered
            If Range("H" & (MainLoop + Secondloop)) = "WIP" Then

                WipSku = Range("F" & (MainLoop + Secondloop))

                Do While TopRow < ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

                    If Range("J" & TopRow) = WipSku Then

                        Do While ThirdLoop < 10

                            childSKU = Range("P" & (TopRow + ThirdLoop))
                            childDesc = Range("Q" & (TopRow + ThirdLoop))
                            childType = Range("R" & (TopRow + ThirdLoop))
                            childPKG = Range("S" & (TopRow + ThirdLoop))

                            Worksheets("Summary 2").Activate

                            Range("A" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) + 1) = childSKU
                            Range("B" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) + 1) = childDesc
                            Range("C" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row) + 1) = childType
                            Range("D" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row) + 1) = childPKG

                            Worksheets("Final").Activate

                            ThirdLoop = ThirdLoop + 1
                        Loop

                    ElseIf Range("J" & TopRow) <> WipSku Then

                        TopRow = TopRow + 1

                    End If

                Loop


                Worksheets("Final").Activate

            'This if does not get triggered even if its true.
            ElseIf Range("H" & (MainLoop + Secondloop)) = "ING" Or Range("H" & (MainLoop + Secondloop)) = "MAT" Or Range("H" & (MainLoop + Secondloop)) = "PKG" Then

                childSKU = Range("F" & MainLoop + Secondloop)
                childDesc = Range("G" & MainLoop + Secondloop)
                childType = Range("H" & MainLoop + Secondloop)
                childPKG = Range("I" & MainLoop + Secondloop)

                Worksheets("Summary 2").Activate

                Range("A" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) + 1) = childSKU
                Range("B" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) + 1) = childDesc
                Range("C" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) + 1) = childType
                Range("D" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) + 1) = childPKG

             Worksheets("Final").Activate

            End If

        Loop

        MainLoop = MainLoop + 20
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting "SecondLoop" anywhere in the sub.  Therefore it's not incrementing.  It seems like this should just run perpeturally because `Do While Secondloop < 20` will never be "not true" since is starts at zero and stays there.

It's hard to say without looking at the data if that is causing your exact problem, but it's definitely an issue.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to send you a copy of the data to give you a better idea? The code still will not work.

Comment: @OriMeir Take a screen grab of your data, upload it to imgur.com, share the link as an image in the original question.  We should be able to reason through it.